# pgfplots: "incorrect" overlap of symbols and lines

Tags: pgfplots

I just noticed that pgfplots appears to first draw all the lines, then all the symbols. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
  \addplot[mark=*,color=red] coordinates {(0.1,0.1) (0.9,0.9)};
  \addplot[mark=*,color=black] coordinates {(0.1,0.09) (0.9,0.91)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's a close-up of part of the output:

[image]

Looking at other parts of the output makes clear that the draw order is:

1. Red line
2. Black line
3. Red symbols
4. Black symbols

which seems "incorrect" to me. Yes, I admit that I should worry about more important things, but how can I get pgfplots to first draw all black items and then all red items (or vice versa)?

Comment: Almost impossible. It probably has something to do with the internal drawing routine. I wouldn't do it with 500 bounty. After all, the *node-flavor* elements are supposed to cover *line* elements. BTW, good MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to what I find `clip mode=individual` does the trick here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xshift=-8cm]
  \addplot[mark=*,color=red] coordinates {(0.1,0.1) (0.9,0.9)};
  \addplot[mark=*,color=black] coordinates {(0.1,0.09) (0.9,0.91)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[clip mode=individual]
  \addplot[mark=*,color=red] coordinates {(0.1,0.1) (0.9,0.9)};
  \addplot[mark=*,color=black] coordinates {(0.1,0.09) (0.9,0.91)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that I would have *thought* that `mark layer=like plot` does the trick, but this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution, which does exactly what I want. (Reading the corresponding section in the manual was useful, though I have to say that I find it counterintuitive that a change to the clipping mode would fix this problem - after all, we don't really clip anything.)

Comment: @user1362373 I agree. From the description one may take that `mark layer=like plot` should do that.

Comment: I suppose that this happens because when clip mode is individual, `pgfplots` has to install and remove the clip for each `addplot` command --- that will end a path and so force the drawing of the nodes associated with it. I suppose that without it the set of `addplot`s are drawn as a single path...